# Apache HttpComponents on Blackberry?

Tags: apache, blackberry

Does anyone know if ApacheHttpComponents

http://hc.apache.org/

will work or can be used with BlackBerry development?

Thanks,

Rasputin.

Answer (score 1):

Not without significant work. HttpComponents depends on JDK classes that don't exist on the BlackBerry. I think it would be possible to port some of it, especially because of the strong separationof interface vs. implementation, but it would be a lot of work to do that.

Comment: well that and the fact that it is coded in 1.5 syntax which will not compile on blackberry ie all generics and foreach style forloops